# Actualizar tabla con sum

Tags: sql, servidor, update

Buen dia Gente, necesito que la columna "Gastos" se vaya sumando a medida que se van ingresando nuevos registros. Trate de hacerlo con un update , funciono en mysql pero al hacerlo en sql server me arroja un error. El id ventas esta con el numero 3 ya que antes de generarlo cargue 2 registros en la tabla.

La tabla como quisiera que me quedara seria asi:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| IdVentas |   Mes |    Gasto |
+----------+-------+----------+
|        1 |     1 |       10 |
|        2 |     1 |       20 |
|        3 | Acum. |       30 |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

Aguardo sus comentarios. Saludos

```
UPDATE
    ventas v,
    (SELECT sum(gasto) as mysum
     FROM ventas
     where idventas <> 3
    ) as s
SET
    v.gasto = s.mysum
WHERE
    v.idventas = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, esto es lo que necesitas...

```html
UPDATE  v set Gasto  = S.mysum 
from Ventas v
inner join 
(    select  sum(Gasto) as mysum
     FROM Ventas v
     where IdVentas <> 3
 
)s
on 1=1
where IdVentas = 3
```